# Wordpress - Change home page on mobile device

Tags: javascript, php, android, wordpress, mobile

I have been searching for some solution to make my home page on mobile devices different than on normal browsers. I need 100% reliable solution but i found only:

- Checking with $is_mobile (it doesn't work in all cases)
- Using JS scripts to calculate device screen. Not sure how to apply that, all the solutions i have found were only useful for some elements on website not to change the home page in genereal.

Is there any solution to that? Most of the posts seems to be outdated also.

Comment: just use a media query to switch it its terrible for SEO but its easy enough to do. Or you use JQuery Mobile but again itl'l hurt your SEO

Comment: The point is that i want to redirect people who enter my website to blog site and completly erase home page from mobile phones. Is it possible to do with media-queries? if so how? Thanks for help

Just for curosity why it is terrible for SEO?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I too spent a lot of time on this topic. I would simply say do not use `wp_is_mobile`. It can be used to load an entirely new page but it is not reliable. And since you are looking for a reliable solution I would say do not use it. It fails.

Rather use javascript to alter different elements of your home page based on the screen size. Also use media queries.

Some important URLs which you might like to read to get more idea :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188881/proper-usage-of-wp-is-mobile

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73273/wp-is-mobile-function

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50219/responsive-theme-design-how-have-slideshow-on-desktops-tablets-and-static-photo/50265#50265